# Make a Content Filter

Tags: javascript, filter

I would like to make a content filter for certain words and then take the words and display them in the console log. 
Here's the js Fiddle link: 
   http://jsfiddle.net/Kz42U/4/

```
var words1 = prompt("Type In Anything");
var words2 = prompt("Type In Anything");
if (words1 == words2){
    alert("Words are Equal");    
}
else {
    alert("Words Are Not Equal");
}
var eliminateWord = function (doubles) {
    if "go" in words1():{
        console.log("user has entered go")
    }
};
```

Comment: `if "go" in words1():` is syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.match`

```
"foo bar mania".match("foo"); // ["foo"]
```

and

```
var word1 = "go",
word2 = "go kart";
var entered = word1.match("word2");
if (entered) {
    console.log("words match");
} else {
    console.log("words don't match"); // output
}
if (word2.match("go")) {
    console.log("user entered go"); // output
}
```

Comment: thanks for that raam86 but how can I get the code to read a txt file and check if its their and if it is then be removed if you can that would be awesome

Comment: @alia well reading a txt file is hard on the browser. You have to look into AJAX  -  Much easier using jQuery. You can replace using 
'"la la la".replace(/la/g, "" );'

Comment: Nothing is hard. You just have to use a search engine